# Show Whole Table After Null Search

Tags: vba, excel

for the code below, if a search comes up empty based on `Criteria1:="Ship"`, then there is nothing to copy, and the code stops at `Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, how can I get rid of this bug? Additionally, I want the whole table to show even if no data meets the criteria. I have the line `Worksheets("Efficiency").ShowAllData` but this is under the assumption the code runs all the way.

Thanks,

```
Sub ImportShipper()    
        Dim wsEff As Worksheet
        Dim wsShip As Worksheet
        Dim wsFirst As Worksheet
        Set wsEff = Worksheets("Efficiency")
        Set wsFirst = Worksheets("1")    
        Set wsShip = ActiveSheet
        wsShip.Name = wsFirst.Range("B34").Value     
        With wsEff
            Dim lRow As Long
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:H" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Ship"
            Dim rngCopy As Range
            'All Columns A:H
            Set rngCopy = .Columns("A:H")
            'filtered rows, not including header row - assumes row 1 is headers
            Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            rngCopy.Copy
            End With
        wsShip.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Worksheets("Efficiency").ShowAllData
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could go like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportShipper()
Dim wsEff As Worksheet
Dim wsShip As Worksheet
Dim wsFirst As Worksheet

Set wsEff = Worksheets("Efficiency")
Set wsFirst = Worksheets("1")
Set wsShip = ActiveSheet
wsShip.Name = wsFirst.Range("B34").value
With wsEff
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A1:H" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Ship"
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(2)) > 0 Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                wsShip.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        End With
    End With
End With

Worksheets("Efficiency").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error at .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy stating "Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the Range class"

Comment: before posting I tested with data in range "A1:H5" (headers in row 1) of sheet "Efficiency". and skipped `Set wsFirst = Worksheets("1")` and `wsShip.Name = wsFirst.Range("B34").value` statements as not peculiar to the desired behavior. Are your data "like" mine? Have you used the very same code of mine?

Comment: yes the data is similar, but the first row is title row.

Comment: How about using something like this? I know the syntax is not correct for the if condition, how can I restate that? With wsEff
    
  
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Set rngCopy = .Columns("A:H")
    If rngCopy Is Empty Then
    Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rngCopy.Copy
    Else
    End If
    End With
    Worksheets("Efficiency").ShowAllData

Comment: `If rngCopy Is Empty` is not a valid statement. nor would work `IsEmpty(rngCopy)` since it'd consider all `rngCopy` cells ignoring their visible property. I think we must stick to the code I proposed since it works with no exception for me. try the _very same_ code I posted and go through every relevant statement: in VBE place a breakpoint (press F9), say, at the `With wsEff` statement, have code run (press F5) and then pressing F8 to go through every statement from that point on. This way you can query every variable value in Immediate Window as well as in Locals Window. or post you sheet

Comment: I get the same error. Is there another strategy that I may use to get around the bug?

Comment: I wouldn’t say since I can't replicate the "bug". Unless you could post a "not working" set of files (not .xlsm!) to test myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109067/discussion-between-kish-and-user3598756).